# How can I put picture in a table!

Tags: tables, tikz-pic

I can put a picture in a table (cheer!), but I want to put a picture `with a caption` in my table and it's caption will disappear. My table includes both a picture and a tikz. how can I do it?

This is code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]  
\begin{center}‎  
\begin{tabular}{|c‎‎|c|}‎  
\hline  
    \begin{figure}[h]‎  
‎   \centering‎  
    ‎\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Pics/01_01.bmp}‎‎‎\\\caption{My Caption‎‎ ‎‎‎$B$‎}  
‎   \label{Gauss1}‎  
    \end{figure}‎‎‎  
    &   
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \begin{axis}  
    [grid=major,samples=30,mark=none]  
    \addplot[blue,very thick,domain=-1:1]  
    {x^3};  
    \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}‎  
\\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}   
    \caption{fig Analysis}   
    \label{tbl:mro}   
\end{center}  
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can use a plain `\includegraphics{…}\\\captionof{figure}{A caption}`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-) working example?

Comment: @Bernard I added code.

Comment: Don't use the `figure` environment. Just use `\includegraphics` on its own.

Comment: But you can't put a \caption inside a tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you can put one inside a `minipage` inside a `tabular`.  Also, you can use `\captionof{figure}` inside a table.

Note: table and figure are floats, whose purpose is to move stuff to the top or bottom of the page.  If you don't want your stuff to move, don't use floats; use a `minipage` and `\captionof` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
  \begin{minipage}[c]{3cm}
    ‎\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}‎‎‎
    \captionof{figure}{My Caption‎‎ ‎‎‎$B$‎}
‎    \label{Gauss1}‎
  \end{minipage}‎‎‎
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \begin{axis}
    [grid=major,samples=30,mark=none]
    \addplot[blue,very thick,domain=-1:1]
    {x^3};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}‎ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}   

\caption{fig Analysis}
\label{tbl:mro}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Don't use `center` in a `table` or `figure` environment, `\centering` is better. If, for some reasons (there can be) `caption` cannot be used, `capt-of` is the package of choice for `\captionof`.

Comment: @egreg - Mea culpa.